# for-of on Array in Safari

Tags: javascript, arrays, safari, undefined-reference

Consider the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cell">div 1 text</div>
        <div class="cell">div 2 text</div>
        <div class="cell">div 3 text</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let list = document.getElementsByClassName("cell")
                for(let y of list){
                    console.log("y:", y)
                }
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

When run in Chrome V55.0, it produces the following console output:

```
y:        <div class="cell">div 1 text</div>
y:        <div class="cell">div 2 text</div>
y:        <div class="cell">div 3 text</div>
```

Firefox V50.1 returns similar results as well.

However when run in Safari 10.0.2, this same file generates an error stating

> TypeError: y of list is not a function. (In 'y of list', 'y of list' is >undefined).

I'm not quite sure what to make of this error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: although Safari 10+ says it has "basic support" for `of`, perhaps a regular old for loop would work?

Comment: Try adding `"use strict";` ?

Comment: That isn't an Array. Safari may not yet have iterator support on DOM collections (not sure). Try converting to an Array: `for (let y of Array.from(list)) {...`

Comment: I'd be curious to know if it works if you use `document.querySelectorAll(".cell")` instead, without converting to an Array. The kind of collection returned is different.